# How to find floating devices in gtkmm

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gdk, gtkmm3

I am unable to find a list of floating devices in gtkmm.

I can find all the seats associated with a display, but these only contain slaves and master devices. Is there a master list that enumerates ***all*** devices (including floating devices)?

I've also tried using `Gdk::DeviceManager`, but this doesn't work (and is being depreciated for future versions).

I have a touchscreen device that I am unable to find the `Gdk::Device` object for- I assume it's a floating device that is unconnected to any signals. If I can find it, I can connect it to signals.

I would really appreciate some help.

Notes: Windows 10/HID-compliant touchscreen driver/Gtkmm3.22/vcpkg install